# jquery sortable: The dropped sortable list item should have a class applied removing similar class in other items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a HTML list

```
<ul id="sections" class="ui-sortable">
  <li class="selected">one</li>
  <li> two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li> four  </li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li> six </li>
</ul>
```

The list is sortable using jQuery UI.

Initially the first list item have a class "selected". If an user drag any item and change the order of the list, the dropped list item in the new place should have a class "selected" & also any other list item class "selected" should be removed.

There can be only one list item with class "selected" at any point of time.

How to achieve this, I am trying using beforestop, stop, change events but i can't figure this out

```
  $( "#sections" ).sortable({
              stop: function( event, ui ) {

                    var present = $(ui.item).addClass("selected");
                    console.log(present);
                  }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $(this).find('.selected').removeClass("selected")

                    var present = $(ui.item).addClass("selected");
                    console.log(present);
                  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Es3Zt/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use .siblings()

```
 $( "#sections" ).sortable({
      stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.item).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
      }
 });
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LBGew/1/)